# Change string in files

Tags: bash

How do we change string in file with other string,

For example we want to change string `Proxy=` in every files to string `Proxy=1080` with command `./changeproxy.sh 1080` and if we run with no arguments `./changeproxy.sh` it will be `"Proxy="` only.

Comment: Have a look at [sed](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sed).

Answer (score 1):

Try the following script:

```
#!/bin/bash
sed -i 's/Proxy=\([0-9]*\)/Proxy='"$2"'/g' "$1"
```

The first argument to the script is the name of the file and the second argument is the new port number.